# Hibernate Lazy/Eager list always grabbing entire list with new addition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-many

I have this class below and when I call addDataException, it goes to the database and grabs ALL the exceptions every time an addition is made.  Can someone explain this and a work around to stop this?

```
@Entity
public class Tenant extends BaseEntity {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<DataException> dataExceptions = new HashSet<>();

public void addDataException(DataException dataException) {
        dataExceptions.add(dataException);
        dataException.setTenant(this);
    }
```

Logs

```
.
.
.
20:21:47.091 [scheduler-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 944
20:21:47.091 [scheduler-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.test.DataException#74645]
20:21:47.093 [scheduler-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Found row of collection: [com.test.dataExceptions#70]
20:21:47.094 [scheduler-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 945
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `Set` and from `Set` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) we get:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

In order to check if the new `DataException` could be added to the collection, it needs to load it from DB first. Due this reason it will trigger loading of data if you perform an `add` operation in a `Set`.

**For your case**

If you are just interested in storing the new `DataException` maybe you could simply store the `DataException` object, if it is already stored you will receive a PK violation, but you will avoid the select to load such collection.

Comment: Why does storing a data exception object with PK of 0 trigger a database grab?  Also if I didnt want to use a set, is there something else I could use?

Comment: Mike, I think you are mixing the concepts, the idea of repeated object could be checked only on application layer (in java it is done by implementing equals and hashcode), the database doesn't know about that and it shouldn't, due this reason fetch is needed before add something to the set. My proposal was to add directly to the database (through persistence layer, without adding it to the set), as your relation is `@OneToMany` with `mappedBy`, next time you fetch all elements from set it will fetch the one saved directly too. Please let me know more details if still not clear.